# View selection of objects among layers in adobe illustrator

Tags: layer, adobe-illustrator

I am looking for some best practices to sort / group different objects across multiple layers in Adobe Illustrator, to be able to select/view a specific selection of objects.

In more detail:
I have a grafic with multiple versions, which are very common, but yet slightly different, hence I want to edit them in one *.ai file

- Same header for all
- Specific highlight for version 1/2
- 3 different languages (EN/DE/ES)
- Specific background for version 1/2

To reduce redundancy I want to create common objects only once, instead of creating a group for each version/langugage for simple showing/hiding and duplicate objects.

My current layer/group structure (as minimum example) would be:

```
1    |_ Header
1.1    |_ HeaderGrafic
2    |_ Highlight
2.1    |_ Higlight_1
2.2    |_ Higlight_2
3    |_ Text
3.1    |_ Text_EN
3.2    |_ Text_DE
3.3    |_ Text_ES
4    |_ Background
4.1    |_ Background_1
4.2    |_ Background_2
```

I am searching for a quick and easy way to switch views to select a specific combination, e.g.

- Version 1 in language EN -> showing only 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 and hiding all others
- Version 2 in language ES -> showing only 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.1 and hiding all others

I tried storing selections, but cannot get to view/hide specific views/selections.

Comment: So, did you get an answer after all? It's not exactly a good thing to ask questions, get answers, and disappear without any feedback. To say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for change **views** it looks like you need the standard commands 'New View', 'Edit Views' in menu 'View':

[image]

As for store **selections** in the same way, well, Illustrator has no such tool as far as I know. Which is yet another example of disgrace of Adobe Illustrator developers. (I can be wrong about latest versions, though).

Of course it can be done with script(s).

Or you can select your objects with actions if you will place object on correct layers. You can lock and unlock the layers with actions (with above mentioned menu commands, as well) and perform the command 'Select All'.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and sorry for the late reply. But VIEWS doesn't seem to work the correct way. I e.g. selected relevant content for "Version 1 in language EN" and stored a new view. Selecting ALL elements afterwards and then applying the stored view some hiding of elements happens, but it's not restoring the desired/stored view.

Comment: This option seems to be the best working one, I cannot get closer to my originally desired structure